# javascript access element using id variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, input, undefined

How to make it work?

When trying to access an input box by id using a variable, the script returns "undefined".

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<table>
  <script>
    const IDs = ["Cell_1", "Cell_2"];

    document.write("<tr><td><input type='text' value='", IDs[0], "' class='qty' id='", IDs[0], "' name='A' ></td>");
    document.write("<td><input type='text' value='10' id='BB' name='B' ></td>");
    document.write("<td><input type='text' value='10' id='", IDs[1], "' name='B' ></td></tr>");

    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write("ID_1: ", IDs[0], "</br>");

    document.write($("#BB").val(), "</br>");
    document.write($("#IDs[1]").val(), "</br>");

    document.write("ID_2: ", IDs[1]);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
  </script>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't have an element with ID `IDs[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
document.write($('#'+IDs[1]).val(), "</br>")
```

If you place IDs[1] in double quotes, it will treat it as string and not render the value of it.